# The while loop in my Hangman game isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
answer = input("Type word here: ").lower()
word_amount = len(answer.split())
maximum_words = 1

while maximum_words != float(word_amount):
    print("False input, 1 Word only!")
    answer = input("Type word here: ").lower
    word_amount = len(answer.split())


counter = 0
while counter != 20:
    counter += 1
    print("Can't see this!!!!!!")

guess_amount = 0
guess = input("Guess the word: ").lower()

while guess_amount != 9:
    if answer == guess:
        guess_amount = 9
        print("You win!!!")
    else:
        print("Nope")
        guess_amount += 1
        guess = input("Guess again: ").lower()

if guess_amount == 9 and answer != guess:
    print("You lose!!!")
```

This is the entire code to my hangman game, where person 1 types in word and then person 2 has 10 tries to guess the word, everything works fine except for this while loop:

```
answer = input("Type word here: ").lower()
word_amount = len(answer.split())
maximum_words = 1

while maximum_words != float(word_amount):
    print("False input, 1 Word only!")
    answer = input("Type word here: ").lower
    word_amount = len(answer.split())
```

When I run the game and type in more then one word the game is supposed to go into a loop and is supposed to  keep on asking to type in one word only. But when I run it, type in more than 1 word and then 1 word(which should stop the loop), it says that "split" is not a defined function and I don't know why that is. Would be glad if someone could help me. Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: ``input("Type word here: ").lower`` just fetches the ``.lower`` method on the string provided by the user. You have to actually *call* it to get the result, i.e. ``input("Type word here: ").lower()``.

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake in this line.

`answer = input("Type word here: ").lower`

You forgot to put brackets after lower.
Just use `lower()` instead of `lower`

You will get the desired output:

```
Type word here: hello how are you
False input, 1 Word only!
Type word here: hello fine
False input, 1 Word only!
Type word here: hello hi
False input, 1 Word only!
Type word here:
```